# Communication between 2 ESP8266 WiFi modules without router using AT commands

Tags: tcp, wifi, at-command, esp8266

I'm trying to make a *TCP* based communication to send a simple message "Hello" from one *ESP8266* module to another using [this document](http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf). I'm using 2 *USB to TTL* as hardware and *Realterm* as serial terminal. 
I could do it when *ESP8266* modules are connected to a router, sending AT commands as below,

Set the Server:

```
AT+CWJAP="AccessPointName","Password"//Join to your WiFi network
AT+CIPMUX=1//0 for single connection 1 for multiple connection.
AT+CIPSERVER=1,1336//Set as Server. 1 to open Server mode(0 to close). 1336 is port.
AT+CIFSR//Get IP address (STAIP 192.168.43.151)
```

Set the Client:

```
AT+CWJAP="AccessPointName","Password"
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSTART=1,"TCP","192.168.43.151",1336//Set up TCP or UDP connection, the 4 parameters are id, type, adress and port.     
AT+CIPSEND=1,7// Channel and number of bytes to send
//After issuing all previous command you will receive "OK". But afterAT+CIPSENDyou will receive a ">" as response.

Hello//send your Data
```

I want to connect both *ESP8266* to each other without a router.
So I used these AT commands:

Server commands:

```
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CWMODE=3//set the module as a client and also an access point.
AT+CIPSERVER=1,1336
AT+CIFSR //Getting 2 ip address (APIP 192.168.4.1 and STAIP 0.0.0.0).
```

Client commands:

```
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+CWJAP="ESP1 SSID", "ESP1 PWD" //Connect to server
AT+CIPSTART=1,"TCP","0.0.0.0",1336 // I also tried APIP 192.168.4.1.
```

But when I send `CIPSTART` command I get `ERROR` message.
What's going wrong? What should I do?

Comment: `I want to connect both ESP8266 to each other without a router.` well so they have to be in the same network in order to communicate with each other. From the last "server commands" it doesn't seem like you open a network. One ESP8266 has to be a router (software-accespoint mode) and the other has to be the client (station mode). Let the server create an access point and let the other join it. (There is also a softap+client mode, in which an ESP can be both an access point and a client in another network, but that's not interessting right now)

Comment: Thanks, I had set modules as both client and access point but forgot to write it down here. Commands added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of a route entry, the 0.0.0.0 means the default route. In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. If a host has two IP addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs. This type of communication is also known as WiFi P2P or Wifi direct. It should work properly with your commands! If problem persists try with different modules.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I thought that I'm doing something wrong with issuing AT commands. I'll try it with different modules.

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to ESP8266_02 using the "Termite" terminal or any other terminal program.
2. Enter the following commands one by one and press Enter after each command:

   ```
   AT
   AT+CIFSR
   AT+CWMODE=2
   AT+CWSAP="DIGITestTe","12345678",1,0
   AT+CIPMUX=1
   AT+CIPSERVER=1,8888
   ```

   These commands set up ESP8266_02 as a SoftAP, configure the Wi-Fi network, enable multiple connections (CIPMUX), and start the server on port 8888.
3. Switch to the ESP8266_01 terminal and connect to ESP8266_01 using the "Termite" terminal or any other terminal program.
4. Enter the following commands one by one and press Enter after each command:

   ```
   AT
   AT+CIFSR
   AT+CWMODE=1
   AT+CWJAP="DIGITestTe","12345678"
   AT+CIPMUX=1
   AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","192.168.4.1",8888
   AT+CIPSEND=0,9
   ```

   These commands set up ESP8266_01 in Station mode, connect to the Wi-Fi network, enable multiple connections (CIPMUX), initiate a TCP connection with ESP8266_02, and set the data length to 9 bytes.
5. After entering `AT+CIPSEND=0,9`, the terminal will display `>`, indicating that you can enter the message to send. Type `hello 02` and press Enter.

   ```
   > hello 02
   ```
6. ESP8266_02 will receive the message "hello 02" and respond with "I have received your greetings 01". ESP8266_01 will automatically receive this response.
7. Now, enter the following commands in the ESP8266_01 terminal:

   ```
   AT+CIPSEND=0,22
   ```

   This sets the data length to 22 bytes.
8. After entering `AT+CIPSEND=0,22`, the terminal will display `>`, indicating that you can enter the message to send. Type `Thanks 01, I'm online` and press Enter.

   ```
   > Thanks 01, I'm online
   ```
9. ESP8266_02 will receive the message "Thanks 01, I'm online" and respond with "OK!". ESP8266_01 will automatically receive this response.

By following these steps, you should be able to repeat the successful communication between ESP8266_01 and ESP8266_02 using AT commands. Make sure to enter the commands accurately and check the terminal responses for any errors or issues.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

I changed modules and it's working now.

The Server Commands:

```
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSERVER=1,222
AT+CIFSR
/*the server response to CIFSR is:
+CIFSR:APIP,"192.168.7.7"                     
+CIFSR:APMAC,"a2:20:a6:10:50:2c"                                              
+CIFSR:STAIP,"0.0.0.0"                                                         
+CIFSR:STAMAC,"a0:20:a6:10:50:2c"*/
```

The Client commands:

```
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+CWJAP="SERVER_SSID","SERVER_PASS"
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSTART=2,"TCP","192.168.7.7",222
AT+CIPSEND=2,7
HELLO
```